# ISSUE: Mysql converting Enum to Int

Tags: mysql, enums, int

I have a very simple rating system in my database where each rating is stored as an enum('1','-1').  To calculate the total I tried using this statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(rating, SIGNED)) as value from table WHERE _id = 1
```

This works fine for the positive 1 but for some reason the -1 are parsed out to 2's.

Can anyone help or offer incite?

Or should I give up and just change the column to a SIGNED INT(1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I'd suggest to change the type of the column. The issue becomes clear when you read the [doc about enum type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) (which strongly recommends not to use numbers as enumeration values!) - the index of the enum item is returned, not the enum value itself.

Comment: Well, it'd be even more descriptive to change the enum values to `up` and `down`!

Comment: Perhaps, but if he needs to do a lot of this kind of "rating arithmetic" it quickly becomes tedious (and slow)... much simpler to operate with "plain integer values".

Comment: yea I went ahead and changed it after posting this question.  Thanks for the explanation tho. Very helpful

Answer (score 24):

this is what you want

```
select enum+0 as enum
```

Answer (score 16):

This conversion to `int` in MySQL for `enum` is only possible:

```
CAST(CAST(`rating` AS CHAR) AS SIGNED) as value from table WHERE _id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys,

Just had a bit of a mere of a time with this one. I learned that i shouldn't use ENUMs where integers are the values. However We had years worth of data and i couldn't alter the database.

This bad boy worked (turning it into a character, then into a signed int).

```
CAST(CAST(`rating` AS CHAR) AS SIGNED) as value from table WHERE _id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT SUM( IF( columnname >0, CAST( columnname AS CHAR ) , NULL ) ) AS vals
FROM `tableName`
```

Comment: Hi! How does this help? Feel free to explain a bit more and to use [code formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use enum here too, but it is still possible in this case to get what is needed

Creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    _id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    rating ENUM('1', '-1')
);
```

Filling table:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, "1"), (2, "1"), (3, "-1"), (4, "-1"), (5, "-1");
```

Performing math operations on enums converts them to indexes, so it is possible just to scale the result value:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(3 - rating * 2)
FROM
    test;
```

Result: `-1` which is true for the test case.