# How to return enum column values as integer in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, enums

I can easily insert into database for enum columns or update them via enum index...
For example I have an enum column `('first','second','third') => (0,1,2)`!
When I want to insert first for column , I will pass the 0 to insert and like this for other values....
How can I get the values now?
For example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE primary_id = 1
```

Now I want to get the enum column value index of this row.
if the enum column value is 'second', how can I get index 1?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using numbers as enumeration value as [enum type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) states in doc. The index of the enum item is returned, not the enum value itself.

Also check here [ISSUE: Mysql converting Enum to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803641/issue-mysql-converting-enum-to-int)