# MySQL set column1 to column2 doesn't set the correct values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Updating the type of field (int) to another (enum) and creating a new field to expand and contract the migration.

I am running `UPDATE table SET newColumn = oldColumn` I don't want the WHERE clause as I want this on the whole table.

When this has ran, the new column has values however they aren't the correct ones?

The values in the initial field are between 0-5 and the second field is an enum 0-5.

Comment: are you trying to change the column TYPE or simply the content values?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming you are trying to replace the values rather than the column data-types)*

You need to tell MySQL to change the data-type so you use [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html):

```
UPDATE table SET newColumn_int = CAST(oldColumn_enum AS UNSIGNED)
```

This converts the ENUM column values into INT (`SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`) data types.

Also see [this very useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803722/3536236)